# iOS Receipt not found

Tags: ios, receipt

I am implementing in-app purchases in a Swift 3.0 app so I need to grab the app receipt to verify it against the iTunes store. Here is how I am getting the receipt:

```
func getReceipt() -> Data? {
    if Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL != nil {
        print("app receipt: \(Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL)")
        do {
            let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL!)
            print(receiptData)
            return receiptData
        } catch {
            print("error converting receipt to Data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

my console output for the receipt URL is:

> app receipt: Optional(file:///Users/dustinspengler/Library/Developer/XCPGDevices/433E8E8F-B781-4ADC-A92D-5CABC28E94D6/data/Containers/Data/Application/C25BE9B6-FB64-4D49-9CF2-9DA371060A7B/StoreKit/receipt)

It then failed to convert the receipt to `Data` and the catch statement prints:

> error converting receipt to Data: The file “receipt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

I get the exact same output when running this in a playground, simulator, and real devices so **does this mean that no receipt exists for the app considering the fact that the user has not made an in-app purchase yet?** When reading through Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1) I got the impression that they are always created created regardless of prior purchases.

Comment: There is no receipt until the user makes *a purchase*. For an app downloaded from the App Store (even a free one). This is *a purchase*, so there will be a receipt. For a debug build from Xcode there is no receipt until an in-app purchase is made.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Paulw11! If you want to submit  this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: considering this info is not listed in Apples documentation, does anyone care to comment on the down down vote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This answer is based off the context that the app is being run on your local machine. If the app is live in the app store, a receipt will be in place the moment you download the app even if its free.**

Answered by @Paulw11:

> There is no receipt until the user makes a purchase. For an app downloaded from the App Store (even a free one). This is a purchase, so there will be a receipt. For a debug build from Xcode there is no receipt until an in-app purchase is made.

Comment: Not sure if this has changed, but I am running iOS 12 and Xcode 10, build from Xcode to my device and was able to get a receipt after calling SKReceiptRefreshRequest.  After that Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL contained a receipt.

Comment: This information is incorrect. As soon as the user downloads an app from the app store, even a free one, there is a receipt, the app's receipt that corresponds to the app's purchase itself. If the app has in-app purchases or subscriptions, then the receipt will contain these purchases too.

Comment: What about TestFlight builds?

Comment: @diachedelic I am not sure about test flight apps. I would imagine since they weren't downloaded from the app store they wont have a receipt but I have not tested.

Comment: They appear not to have a receipt, I was just wondering if it was documented anywhere.